# F# Pattern-matching by type

Tags: f#, pattern-matching

How pattern-matching by type of argument works in F#?

For example I'm trying to write simple program which would calculate square root if *number* provided or return it's argument otherwise.

```
open System

let my_sqrt x =
  match x with
  | :? float as f -> sqrt f
  | _ -> x


printfn "Enter x"
let x = Console.ReadLine()

printfn "For x = %A result is %A" x (my_sqrt x)

Console.ReadLine()
```

I get this error:

```
error FS0008: This runtime coercion or type test from type
    'a    
 to 
    float    
involves an indeterminate type based on information prior 
to this program point. Runtime type tests are not allowed
on some types. Further type annotations are needed.
```

Since `sqrt` works with `float` I check for `float` type, but guess there could be better solution - like check if input is *number* (in general) and if so, cast it to float?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem here is that the type of `x` is actually a `string`. Adding that it comes from `Console.ReadLine`, what kind of information is stored in that string is only possible to determine at runtime. This means that you can't use neither pattern matching, nor pattern matching with coercion here.

But you can use [Active Patterns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233248.aspx). As what actual data is stored in `x` is only known at runtime, you have to parse the string and see what is contains.

So suppose you are expecting a `float`, but you can't be sure since user can input whatever they want. We are going to try and parse our string:

```
let my_sqrt x =
    let success, v = System.Single.TryParse x // the float in F# is represented by System.Single in .NET
    if success then sqrt v
    else x
```

But this won't compile:

> This expression was expected to have type     float32     but here has type     string

The problem is that the compiler inferred the function to return a `float32`, based on the expression `sqrt (System.Single.Parse(x))`. But then if the `x` doesn't parse to float, we intend to just return it, and as `x` is a string we have an inconsistency here.

To fix this, we will have to convert the result of `sqrt` to a string:

```
let my_sqrt x =
    let success, v = System.Single.TryParse x
    if success then (sqrt v).ToString()
    else x
```

Ok, this should work, but it doesn't use pattern matching. So let's define our "active" pattern, since we can't use regular pattern matching here:

```
let (|Float|_|) input =
    match System.Single.TryParse input with
    | true, v -> Some v
    | _ -> None
```

Basically, this pattern will match only if the `input` can be correctly parsed as a floating point literal. Here's how it can be used in your initial function implementation:

```
let my_sqrt' x =
    match x with
    | Float f -> (sqrt f).ToString()
    | _ -> x
```

This looks a lot like your function, but note that I still had to add the `.ToString()` bit.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This will fail if 'x' is not a string - which I assume is the real challenge here.

Comment: It's a *really* bad idea to use try/catch within your active patterns (for performance reasons) unless absolutely necessary. In this case, you should use `System.Single.TryParse` to attempt to parse the value, and you can use the automatic tupling feature of the F# match statement to handle the output.

Comment: I still do not understand the phrase "...what kind of information is stored in that string is only possible to determine at runtime. This means that you can't use neither pattern matching, nor pattern matching with coercion here...", but from the error message "...Further type annotations are needed", it seems to me that `let my_sqrt (x:obj) =` should work.

Answer (score 2):

Just quoting the one and only Scott Wlaschin's ['F# for fun and profit' site](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/match-expression/):

> Matching on subtypes You can match on subtypes, using the :? operator,
>   which gives you a crude polymorphism:
>
> ```
> let x = new Object()
> let y = 
>     match x with 
>     | :? System.Int32 -> 
>         printfn "matched an int"
>     | :? System.DateTime -> 
>         printfn "matched a datetime"
>     | _ -> 
>         printfn "another type"
> ```
>
> This only works to find subclasses of a parent class (in this case,
>   Object). The overall type of the expression has the parent class as
>   input.
>
> Note that in some cases, you may need to “box” the value.
>
> ```
> let detectType v =
>     match v with
>         | :? int -> printfn "this is an int"
>         | _ -> printfn "something else"
> // error FS0008: This runtime coercion or type test from type 'a to int  
> // involves an indeterminate type based on information prior to this program point. 
> // Runtime type tests are not allowed on some types. Further type annotations are needed.
> ```
>
> The message tells you the problem: “runtime type tests are not allowed
>   on some types”. The answer is to “box” the value which forces it into
>   a reference type, and then you can type check it:
>
> ```
> let detectTypeBoxed v =
>     match box v with      // used "box v" 
>         | :? int -> printfn "this is an int"
>         | _ -> printfn "something else"
>
> //test
> detectTypeBoxed 1
> detectTypeBoxed 3.14
> ```
>
> In my opinion, matching and dispatching on types is a code smell, just
>   as it is in object-oriented programming. It is occasionally necessary,
>   but used carelessly is an indication of poor design.
>
> In a good object oriented design, the correct approach would be to use
>   polymorphism to replace the subtype tests, along with techniques such
>   as double dispatch. So if you are doing this kind of OO in F#, you
>   should probably use those same techniques.